# how to stop video autoplay in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, video, autoplay

```
<video  class="img-responsive" controls="controls" autostart="false">
<source  ng-src="{{data[0].media.split(',')[0]}}" > 
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

autoplay was stop without angularjs. 
 But i don't know how to stop autoplay using angular js coding.

Comment: If you want to do so, write a directive. No, need. this is fine. But why require it in angular?

Comment: I need it in angular for dynamic content. do you have any solution to solve it.

Comment: `dynamic` content means what?  If you want load videos dynamically, `ng-src` will do it. What is the relation between dynamic loading and autoplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using directive:

```
  .directive("pause", function() {
     return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
          auto: '@'
      }
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
          var ele = angular.element(ele)[0];
          if(scope.auto) {
              ele.autoplay = true;
          }
          else {
              ele.autoplay = false;
          }
      }
   }
 })
```

In html:

```
<video  class="img-responsive" controls="controls" pause auto="false">
   <source  ng-src="{{data[0].media.split(',')[0]}}" > 
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: when my website is loading, by default the auto value is true.

Comment: so i changed your coding

Comment: .directive("pause", function() {
     return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
          auto: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
          var ele = angular.element(ele)[0];
          if(scope.auto) {
              ele.autoplay = false;
          }
          else {
              ele.autoplay = true;
          }
      }
   };
 })

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether it has autostart attributes using `angular.element('video').attr('autostart')`

but I have same question. why need this? just use attributes in html